# Raccourcir la phrase « Effacer les paramètres de recherche »

Tags: anglais, choix-de-mot, informatique

Comment est-ce que je peux écrire « clear search parameters » comme ci-dessous, mais en plus court ? C'est pour un bouton web.

> Effacer les paramètres de recherche

L'opposé de la phrase est:

> Enregistrer filtre de recherche

Mes suggestions:

- *Effacer filtre*
- *Supprimer filtre*

[image]

Comment: Pourquoi pas 'Sans filtrage' ou 'Sans filtre'. Sans voir le reste de l'interface il est difficile d’évaluer s'il y a assez de context pour que cela soit intuitif.

Comment: Tu devrais essayer de mettre ça sur le site UX.StackExchange! Parce qu'avec un meilleur UI tu n'aurais surement pas besoin de plus que "Supprimer"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si votre interface est assez explicite,
« *Supprimer les filtres* »
est suffisant.